# Firebase firestore get data from collections documents and then subcollection documents in one array

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I am using node server with express and trying to get data from the firestore database. My database structure is as follows

```
-Resource Collection
  - Documents with fields
     - comments subcollection
         - documents with fields
     - subresource subcollection
         - documents with fields
```

I am trying to map all the above data in a single array with subresource and comments being nested array inside the single array. Following is my code. The log has the correct data in one array but when I am sending the response back it only shows 1 resource and that too is random everytime. Shouldnt promise.all then block execute after all the data has been collected? Am i even using the promises correctly?

```
    response.set('Cache-Control','public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
    db.collection('Resources').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        let Resources = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
            var promises = [];
            let documentData = doc.data();
            documentData['id'] = doc.id;
            promises.push(db.collection('Resources').doc(documentData.id).collection('SubResources').get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                documentData['subresources'] = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    let subResourceData = doc.data();
                    subResourceData['id'] = doc.id;
                    return subResourceData;   
                })
            }));
            promises.push(db.collection('Resources').doc(documentData.id).collection('Comments').get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                documentData['comments'] = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    return doc.data();  
                })
            }));
            Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
                console.log(documentData);
                return response.json(documentData);            
            })
        })        

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not recommend normalizing the database, but quite the opposite, de-anomalizing it.

Comment: remember that firebase is a faas

Comment: I explain, based on your data model, you have to focus on the representation of the information in the view, no matter the redundancy of data. Since firebase is a faas.

Comment: In 'resource collection' the most crucial data of comments and subresource to represent it in the view.

Comment: Your Promise.all() catches the promises of fetching subresource and comments only, and not the "Resource"s themselves. so for whichever Resource it can complete fetching the subresource and comments first, it resolves and returns the data.

Comment: @AsifM - So should I put the Resources get inside the promise too?

Comment: @FrFernandez - I thought about bringing comments and subresource under document as array of maps. But the problem is that I want to use the firebase unique id to update and delete those sub resource and comments. Which would be difficult if they are just added to the document without a reference id.

Comment: But it is clearly necessary to represent the resources with their comments and sub-resources in a single instance.

Comment: I propose it as an example, when you load a video from youtube, the first thing that is loaded is the information related to the video, then the secondary information is loaded.

Comment: Because representing all the information in one endpoint alone, with firebase it is not an optimal way.

However, it is better to divide it into several endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Promise.all() catches the promises of fetching subresource and comments only, and not the "Resource"s themselves. so for whichever Resource it can complete fetching the subresource and comments first, it resolves and returns the data.

Below is a slight modification to your code so that it waits for all the Resources to complete pulling comments/subresources and then returns them as an array.

```
response.set('Cache-Control','public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');

db.collection('Resources').get()
.then(snapshot => {
    let ResourcePromises = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        var promises = [];
        let documentData = doc.data();
        documentData['id'] = doc.id;
        promises.push(db.collection('Resources').doc(documentData.id).collection('SubResources').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            documentData['subresources'] = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                let subResourceData = doc.data();
                subResourceData['id'] = doc.id;
                return subResourceData;   
            })
        }));
        promises.push(db.collection('Resources').doc(documentData.id).collection('Comments').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            documentData['comments'] = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                return doc.data();  
            })
        }));
        return Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
            //console.log(documentData);
            //return response.json(documentData);            
            return documentData;
        })
    });

    Promise.all(ResourcePromises).then(function(allResources) {
        return response.json(allResources);
    })

})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```

You may want to refactor the code to separate functions so that they're more readable.

Comment: I tried to update the code as you mentioned but i am getting an undefined array back from the promise.all(resourcepromises)

Comment: I have updated the code that had a typo and a missing return- which you can give a try now. In any case, I hope the explanation as to why your code was returning random single documents is clear now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. I understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much explaining this in detail.

Comment: Only solution I found that works. Thank you!